# Android ExpandableListView: group item does not expand/collapse

Tags: android

So, I have an `ExpandableListView`, which expands and collapses fine, when I tap on the group list item. Then I add a a button to the group view, and expanding and collapsing stops working. It just doesn't respond to tapping, even if the tapping is outside of the button. I suspect the button is somehow interfering with the group view. But I couldn't figure out how. Any ideas? Thanks.

A simple repro:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="40dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="I am expandable" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="foo"
        android:src="@drawable/foo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Dependency](https://github.com/DevAhamed/MultiViewAdapter) for use of this you get a pre-define adepter and you can easily modify this It's work me I hope it works for you